# When to set configuration variables for company-mode

Tags: company-mode

I have a function that calls `global-company-mode` with argument `1` (enable) or `-1` (disable).

A user can enable and disable however many times he wants.  Do I have to set the configuration variables for company-mode every time I enable `global-company-mode`?  Or would emacs remember the settings done before the first call that enables `global-company-mode`?

Comment: They are global variables so they will keep their values for ever.

Comment: They became available upon package installation, whether the mode is enabled or not?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by `installation`. From my POV, they become available generally when the package is initialized (loaded into Emacs), although you can set options before that (in which case they are "available" but they are not of much use). But in any case, you don't need to reset them before every enablement of the mode.

Comment: Yes, by `require` if I have the source code, or with `install` with `list-packages`.

Comment: You have some strange ideas: `require` ultimately does a `load` and it does not care if the file it loads is a `.el` file or a `.elc` file. Package initialization (*not* installation) does the same thing: it's just that in  most cases, package *installation* compiles the `.el` files and produces `.elc` files, so package initialization ends up loading `.elc` files. That's all.

Comment: And BTW, you have the source code always. E.g. when I used the package system to install `company`, I got a directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/company-20220425.1145` and all the sources (the `.el` files) are in there, as well as the compiled (`.elc`) files. `package-initialize` which is called automatically before your init file is processed, arranges to set the `load-path` appropriately and load all the installed packages.

Comment: I did not know that you the source code always.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [company-mode manual](http://company-mode.github.io/manual/Getting-Started.html#Initial-Setup):

> To activate the company-mode, execute the command `M-x company-mode` that **toggles the mode on and off**. When it is switched on, the mode line (see (emacs)Mode line) should indicate its presence with an indicator ‘company’.

So do not play with `global-company-mode` at all, just use the function
`company-mode` to do that. You may write a small function for that and
bind it to some key(s).